# How can I solve incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in Laravel Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

My Laravel Eloquent is like this:

```
$products = Product::where('status', 1)
            ->where('stock', '>', 0)
            ->where('category_id', '=', $category_id)
            ->groupBy('store_id')
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->take(4)
            ->get();
```

When executed, there exists an error like this:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1
> of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
> column 'myshop.products.id' which is not functionally dependent on
> columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
> sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `products` where
> `status` = 1 and `stock` > 0 and `category_id` = 5 group by `store_id`
> order by `updated_at` desc limit 4)

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 78):

I had a similar problem and solved it by disabling the MySQL strict mode in the database connection settings.

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        // Behave like MySQL 5.6
        'strict' => false,

        // Behave like MySQL 5.7
        'strict' => true,
    ]
]
```

You can find even more configuration settings in [this blog post by Matt Stauffer](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2).

Comment: if we make 'strict' => false then it may give security bug

Comment: after a day wasted come here and this solved my problem

Comment: @naabster thank you, you probably saved me a day trying to figure this out. Question: is there is any downside to not using strict here? Another comment mentioned the security bug. In my case raw SQL was working but when I went through Laravel (Query builder, 5.6) I got the "only full group" error.

Comment: Took a while 'till I find this answer. Best solution. Thank you so much!
Please, OP. Mark this as right answer.

Answer (score 30):

### Do *not* disable `strict` or `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`!

You should not disable `strict` or remove `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. The problem is that your query is ambiguous, and that's something you need to fix. It *might* not make a difference to your output, but it might also cause huge problems. It's better to be sure.

A great explanation can be read on [Percona](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/05/13/solve-query-failures-regarding-only_full_group_by-sql-mode/) (summed up below).

### Let's look at the problem

Consider the following situation:

```
+----+--------------------+---------+---------------------+
| id | page_url           | user_id | ts                  |
+----+--------------------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | /index.html        |       1 | 2019-04-17 12:21:32 |
|  2 | /index.html        |       2 | 2019-04-17 12:21:35 |
|  3 | /news.php          |       1 | 2019-04-17 12:22:11 |
|  4 | /store_offers.php  |       3 | 2019-04-17 12:22:41 |
|  5 | /store_offers.html |       2 | 2019-04-17 12:23:04 |
|  6 | /faq.html          |       1 | 2019-04-17 12:23:22 |
|  7 | /index.html        |       3 | 2019-04-17 12:32:25 |
|  8 | /news.php          |       2 | 2019-04-17 12:32:38 |
+----+--------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

Now we want to issue a query to calculate the most visited pages. This is probably what you're used to writing:

```sql
SELECT page_url, user_id, COUNT(*) AS visits
FROM web_log
GROUP BY page_url
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

But look at the results:

```
+-------------------+---------+--------+
| page_url          | user_id | visits |
+-------------------+---------+--------+
| /index.html       |       1 |      3 |
| /news.php         |       1 |      2 |
| /store_offers.php |       3 |      2 |
| /faq.html         |       1 |      1 |
+-------------------+---------+--------+
```

The query works, but it’s not really correct. It is easily understandable that `page_url` is the column of the grouping function, the value we are most interested in and we want to be unique for counting. Also, the `visits` column is good, as it’s the counter. But what about `user_id`? What does this column represent?

We grouped on the `page_url` so the value returned for `user_id` is just one of the values in the group. In fact, it was not only user to visit the index.html, as users 2 and 3 visited the page. So what should we make of that value? Is it the first visitor? Is it the last one?

We don’t know the right answer! The `user_id` column’s value is a random item of the group!

### The Solution

You need to consider if you need the values not used in the `groupBy()`. If not, then just use a `select()` to explicitly name the column you need.

If you *do* need a column not used in the `groupBy()`, use an aggregate function (like `SUM()` or `GROUP_CONCAT()` or `MAX()`) as part of a Laravel `selectRaw` query. Then you can be sure that your query is giving you what you expect.

If you know it doesn't matter (like in this example), then there's a miscellaneous function called `ANY_VALUE()` that makes it clear that any value will do.

So in the above example, you could do:

```sql
SELECT page_url, ANY_VALUE(user_id), COUNT(*) AS visits
FROM web_log
GROUP BY page_url
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Or in Laravel/Eloquent:

```php
WebLog::selectRaw('page_url', 'ANY_VALUE(user_id)', 'COUNT(*) AS visits')
->groupBy('page_url')
->orderBy('visits')
->get();
```

Now you are clearly stating that the value doesn't matter, rather than trusting you haven't made a mistake. And if it *does* matter (and you don't apply `ANY_VALUE()`) then MySQL will alert you to the problem.

Here's a list of available [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html).

Answer (score 22):

In folder **config** → **database.php**, make sure `mysql` **strict** is ***false***, like this:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

If strict is true, make it false and then clear the configuration cache by running this command in cmd:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Thankyou,  your `'strict' => false` suggestion works fine for me

Comment: Re *"cmd"*: Do you mean Windows' [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)? Or the command line (in general)?

Answer (score 22):

I solved this problem by adding the "modes" option and setting only the modes I wanted to be enabled in **config => database.php**:

```
'mysql' => [
    ...
    'modes' => [
        'STRICT_ALL_TABLES',
        'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
        'NO_ZERO_DATE',
        'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
        'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
    ],
],
```

See more details in [this tutorial](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2/).

Answer (score 16):

That's because the latest versions of MySQL behave like most DBMSes already do regarding `group by` clauses; the general rule is

> if you're using `group by`, all columns in your `select` must be either present in the `group by` or aggregated by an aggregation function (`sum`, `count`, `avg` and so on)

Your current query is grouping by `store_id`, but since you're selecting everything, the rule above is not respected.

Comment: If I run this query : `select * from products where status = 1 and stock > 0 and category_id = 5 group by store_id order by updated_at desc limit 4` in mysql, it works. It seems that the error is therefore via eloquent laravel

Comment: I like this answer (which explains WHY this is happening) far more than simply 'turn off strict mode'! Changing the query seems more appropriate & 'local' than turning off a much more global setting. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by setting modes in config/database.php file.

Set modes as follows:

```
'modes'  => [
                'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
            ]
```

for mysql driver

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'modes'  => [
            'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: It worked by removing `'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'` from the list.

Answer (score 4):

Check the query:

```
Product::where('status', 1)
            ->where('stock', '>', 0)
            ->where('category_id', '=', $category_id)
            ->groupBy('store_id')
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->take(4)
            ->get();
```

Here you are grouping the data by `store_id` and fetching all columns in the result set which is not allowed. To solve it either select `store_id` or aggregate function on it or change the system variable `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` to `SET sql_mode = ''`.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

To set this in Laravel, try

```
'strict' => false
```

in your *config/database.php* file. In array connections => mysql =>.

Comment: If I run this query : `select * from products where status = 1 and stock > 0 and category_id = 5 group by store_id order by updated_at desc limit 4` in mysql, it works. It seems that the error is therefore via eloquent laravel

Comment: how to set sql mode in laravel?

Comment: how to change SET sql_mode = '' on shared server?

Answer (score 3):

In the **.env** file, *add* variable `DB_STRICT=false`.

And *replace* in the file from the location:

**config/database.php**, next codes `'strict' => true` ON
`'strict' => (env('DB_STRICT', 'true') === 'true' ?  true : false)`.

Comment: I have done it in Lumen 8 but still not working, any other suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *"next codes"*? Do you mean *"the [following](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/following#Noun) code"*?

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround and to prevent further security issues, I make it happen like this:

```
 public function getLatestModels (){
        \DB::statement("SET SQL_MODE=''");
        $latestInserted = Glasses::with('store.deliveryType','glassesHasTags','glassesHasColors','glassesHasSizes','glassesHasImages','glassesBrand','glassesMaterial')->whereRaw("store_id in (select distinct store_id from glasses)")->groupBy('store_id')->orderBy('created_at')->take(8)->get();
        \DB::statement("SET SQL_MODE=only_full_group_by");

        return $latestInserted;
    }
```

This is a kind of combination of other answers.
Also, if you are using
"use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;"
you don't need backslashes in those DB statements above.

The only disadvantage here is that we are making three calls to the database :(

PS: As I see [Felipe Pena's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776758/how-can-i-solve-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by-in-laravel-laravel/55874863#55874863), I guess the second statement is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

To select only aggregated columns, use the one of the [raw methods provided by Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions). For example:

```
Product::selectRaw('store_id')
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->groupBy('store_id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the following method in your helper file:

```
if (!function_exists('set_sql_mode')) {
/**
 * @param string $mode
 * @return bool
 */

    function set_sql_mode($mode = '')
    {
        return \DB::statement("SET SQL_MODE=''");
    }
}
```

Then call set_sql_mode(''); just before Eloquent/query.

Comment: This nukes the whole setting. You might want to extract only ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from it..

Comment: Is this a bogus answer? Does it have any merit?

Answer (score 0):

As said, set strict mode to false may give security bugs. I set *sql_mode* to empty before queries that require it.

Note that it is a *temporary* change. Once your connection is closed (by Laravel request), you will be set to the original sql_mode=only_full_group_by (or beyond).

```
DB::statement("SET sql_mode = '' ");
```

PS: It’s not Laravel's fault. If you try to execute this query directly on your database, you will face the same result. This workaround works in MySQL as well as the first statement and again, will be a temporary session change, not permanent.

Comment: I am using Lumen 8. I have added this statement "DB::statement("SET sql_mode = '' ");" in constructor of every controller and it worked for me. Thanks dear.

Answer (score 0):

All these answers may solve your problem in short term

```
set

'strict' => false

in your config/database.php file. In array connections => mysql =>
```

But you have many problems in the future. For example, we set this configuration only in one of our microservices last year and last week our support team reported a strange bug.

The main reason for this bug is strict=false that we apply it on our configuration file.

> when we want to insert a record to field this set 0 and didn't return
> or log any errors or exceptions. we have many customers with 0 data.

The second bad news is we need to test all last year's commits from the beginning of when we set this configuration.

You should know this configuration has many side effects. On your test scenarios and also on your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I would group the results on the collection instead. So fetch the data from the database.

```
$products = Product::where('status', 1)
            ->where('stock', '>', 0)
            ->where('category_id', '=', $category_id)
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->take(4)
            ->get();
```

Then on the collection:

```
$products->groupBy('store_id');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```php
config()->set('database.connections.mysql.strict', false);
DB::reconnect();
```

Comment: if you don't use the reconnect it will default to what was in the connect, in case you done other querys already

Comment: Well if the connect is strict then this is more than valid