# Laravel Query Builder - groupBy, map, sortBy / orderBy

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

The idea is to get the top sale products from the order table.

```
Order::select('product_id', 'price')->get()->groupBy('product_id')
    ->map(function ($row) {
       return $row->count('product_id');
});
```

The Order table looks like this

[image]

I get something like:

```
product_id: count

"8" : 2,
"34": 1,
"36": 1,
"28": 1,
"31": 1,
"40": 1,
"44": 1,
"46": 1,
"47": 2
```

But I still need to order by the count. How do I do it?

Expected

```
"8" : 2,
"47": 2,
"34": 1,
"36": 1,
"28": 1,
"31": 1,
"40": 1,
"44": 1,
"46": 1,
```

Comment: can you provide more detail about your requirement please

Comment: You can use the `sortBy` or `sortByDesc` method on your collection.

Comment: @adam, how? Can you please give me an example code? I tried it but I don't get what I need

Comment: @SagarGautam, I've updated my question.

Comment: @owen I've added my answer, take a moment to try the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sortBy` method on your collection:

```
Order::select('product_id', 'price')->get()->groupBy('product_id')
->map(function ($row) {
   return $row->count('product_id');
})->sortBy('count');
```

If you wish to sort descending:

```
Order::select('product_id', 'price')->get()->groupBy('product_id')
->map(function ($row) {
   return $row->count('product_id');
})->sortByDesc('count');
```

If you wish to sort using sql:

```
Order::select('product_id', 'price',\DB::raw('COUNT(product_id) as count'))
->groupBy('product_id', 'price')
->orderBy('count')->get();
```

**Note:** You may need to specify the columns in your select clause in your `->groupBy`:

```
->groupBy('product_id', 'price')
```

Comment: *Note: You may need to specify the columns in your select clause in your ->groupBy:* give me a big clue to solve this problem. I end up having to remove 'price' from ::select() because I only want to group by 'product_id_count'. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
Order::select('product_id', 'price',\DB::raw("COUNT('product_id') as product_count"))->groupBy('product_id')->havingRaw("COUNT('product_id') > ?", [0])->orderBy('product_id','ASC')->get();
```

Comment: Your code is sort by product_id. What I need is sort by the number of count of the  product_id

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check if this works for you?

Comment: Hmm. No luck. I get this error. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'database.orders.price' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `product_id`, `price`, COUNT('product_id') as product_count from `orders` group by `product_id` order by `product_id` asc)

Comment: Uhmm maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776758/how-can-i-solve-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by-in-laravel-eloquen) can help you

Comment: @owen You'll need to match the columns in your select clause with your group by. So if your select clause contains product_id,  and price the group by will need these columns specified as well. The column `product_count` does not need to by in the group by clause as it is computed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
Order::select('product_id', 'price',\DB::raw('COUNT(product_id) as count'))->groupBy('product_id')->orderBy('count')->get();
```

Here, raw query is used to count the product ids and then grouped so that we can get count for each product id and then finally ordered by count as per requirement.

I hope you will understand and if any explanation needed regarding above code, feel free to ask.

Comment: I get this error. 

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'database.orders.price' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `product_id`, `price`, COUNT(product_id) as count from `orders` group by `product_id` order by `count` asc)