# (Laravel) can't use group by with order by

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use order by without adding the order column in groupby, it only works if I execute it directly from the database  but from laravel I get database error

I made this eloquent code

```
Comment::select('product_id')->where('shop_name', $shop)->groupby('product_id')->distinct()->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(12)
```

it will product the following query

> select distinct DISTINCT(product_id) from `comments` where `shop_name`
>   = 'shopname' group by `product_id` order by `created_at` asc limit 12 offset 0

if I rub the above query directly in database it works

but if I use Laravel eloquent  code  it fires this error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'areviews_areviewzappz.comments.created_at' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL:
>   select distinct DISTINCT(product_id) from `comments` where `shop_name`
>   = 'shopname' group by `product_id` order by `created_at` asc limit 12 offset 0)

how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: You could add the `created_at` in the `groupBy`

Comment: Whats `distinct DISTINCT(product_id)` ?   `DISTINCT` is a keyword not a function in MySQL i wonder why laravel generates this SQL?? Besides DISTINCT is generated double.. "if I rub the above query directly in database it works" Yes it "works" but you can get **invalid data** because it's not ANSI SQL valid..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues is that you SHOULD really include the ORDER BY in the GROUP BY list as this is best practise.

The reason it works when you are on the the sql mode set to ''. However, Laravel by default (I think) has Strict as TRUE,

You have 2 options:

1. Add the created_at to the GROUP BY clause (Recommended)
2. Change the strict mode to false

A bit more info on the 2nd option:

[How can I solve incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in laravel eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776758/how-can-i-solve-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by-in-laravel-eloquen)

Comment: Hello,  if I included both  I will get different results  in Pagination for example.  if I used product_id  only   I get 88 page  but If I use product_id with created_at  as you suggested  I will get 4444 page and that not what I want.  I will check the second solution it might be what I need thank you.

Comment: Changing strict mode to false solved the issue.  Thank you very much