# Problem on group by SQL request in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I have my SQL request which works in phpmyadmin but in the eloquent request it does not work because of the group by

Please help me and thank you in advance!

```
Code php(Laravel) $top10 = sales::where('id_user', Auth::id())
                                    ->whereYear('created_at', $currentYear)
                                    ->whereMonth('created_at', $currentMonth)
                                    ->selectRaw('id_article, COUNT(*) as count')
                                    ->groupBy('id_article')
                                    ->orderByDesc('count')
                                    ->limit(10)
                                    ->get();
Request SQL : select id_article, COUNT(*) as count, id_client from `ventes` where `id_user` = 2 and year(`created_at`) = 2020 and month(`created_at`) = 06 group by `id_article` order by `count` desc limit 10
```

Comment: You can't include non-grouped by or non aggregated column in select such as `id_client` -- it is better to include `id_user` in group by clause and replace `get` with `->get(['id_article', 'id_user', DB::raw('count(*) as count')]);` -- If you still want to do it without it, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776758/how-can-i-solve-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by-in-laravel-eloquen

Comment: thanks this solved the problem:
'connections' => [
     'mysql' => [
         // Behave like MySQL 5.6
         'strict' => false,

         // Behave like MySQL 5.7
         'strict' => true,
     ]
]

But say you know if the problem can appear with pgsql because it's heroku I use in production

Cordialemet!

Comment: i think, it is better to fix your query/data model to make proper group by.

Comment: It is because it does not work that I opted for this solution ... even with the method that you gave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything seems to be going well now with this request:

```
$top10 = Ventes::where('id_user', Auth::id())
                                    ->whereYear('ventes.created_at', $currentYear)
                                    ->whereMonth('ventes.created_at', $currentMonth)
                                    ->join('stocks', 'stocks.id', '=', 'ventes.id_article')
                                    ->groupBy('id_article', 'name', 'stocks.username')
                                    ->orderByDesc('count')
                                    ->limit(10)
                                    ->get(['id_article', 'name', 'stocks.username AS username', DB::raw('count(*) as count')]);
```

all the columns that I select I put them in the group by also