# Getting unique values GROUPBY, DISTINCT, UNIQUE - what to choose? PHP Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

What I'm trying to do is to get top 5 player scores from database. I'm keeping player data in 3 tables, so it's more complicated.

Right now I'm getting scores, but having problem with making them unique per user.

In top 5, one player can appear only once (even if he has top 5 scores on own)

Current query:

```
DB::table('gameplays', 'gameplay')
            ->join('users', 'gameplay.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->join('playerdatas', 'gameplay.user_id', '=', 'playerdatas.user_id')
            ->select([ DB::raw('DISTINCT(gameplay.user_id)'), 'users.name', 'gameplay.score', 'gameplay.duration', 'gameplay.created_at', 'playerdatas.appearance'])
            ->where('gameplay.created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays($type))
            ->where('gameplay.game_id', '=', $game_id)
            ->orderBy('gameplay.score', 'DESC')
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();
```

So `DISTINCT` not work for me, getting all scores not unique per user.

Tryied also with:

```
->distinct('gameplay.user_id')
->groupBy('gameplay.user_id')
->unique('gameplay.user_id')
```

It was working with `->unique('gameplay.user_id')` on collection but I would like to make that in query not on collection, because I'm currenlty limiting results to 5, so I would miss some records.

```
Tables:

games
|id|name |
|1 |game1|

users
|id|name|
| 1|test|
| 2|elo |
| 3| me |
| 4| 3f2|
| 5| 123|

playerdatas
|id|user_id|game_id|appereance|
| 1| 1     |     1 |  null    |
| 1| 2     |     1 |  null    |
| 1| 3     |     1 |  null    |
| 1| 4     |     1 |  null    |
| 1| 5     |     1 |  null    |

gameplays
|id|game_id|score|created_at|user_id|
| 1| 1     | 100 |24.07.2020| 1     |
| 1| 1     | 700 |24.07.2020| 1     |
| 1| 1     | 400 |24.07.2020| 2     |
| 1| 1     | 300 |24.07.2020| 3     |
| 1| 1     | 200 |24.07.2020| 1     |
| 1| 1     | 400 |24.07.2020| 2     |
| 1| 1     | 500 |24.07.2020| 3     |
| 1| 1     | 100 |24.07.2020| 2     |
| 1| 1     | 200 |24.07.2020| 3     |
| 1| 1     | 100 |24.07.2020| 1     |
| 1| 1     | 900 |24.07.2020| 2     |
| 1| 1     | 870 |24.07.2020| 3     |
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add the various tables in the post?

Comment: Also your mysql version.

Comment: @Aashishgaba updated post with tables

Comment: @P.Salmon mysql:5.7

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the raw sql. With that in mind, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing answer to let you know what I finally did to sort that problem.

I've created raw SQL in laravel with `GROUP BY`, but that wasn't all. The problem was that is you using `GROUP BY` now (latest versions of MySQL) you have to either add all selected columns to `GROUP BY` or aggregated them by one of functions (`MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, etc.). If you don't do that you will get error:

```
this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

source: [How can I solve incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in laravel eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776758/how-can-i-solve-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by-in-laravel-eloquen)

So to bypass that error and make `GROUP BY` work for that case I had to switch in laravel database.php mysql mode to not strict mode

```
 'mysql' => [
            'strict' => false,
```

This is not ideal solution, only temporary one for now, but it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` in a `subquery` to group the users based on the total scores. Then join that to `playerdata` to get information from that table. Here is an **example** (you can add `where` conditions based on your requirement):

First, the subquery bit:

```
$scores = DB::table('gameplays')
            ->select(DB::raw('MAX(score) as max_score'), //edited after your comment
                   DB::raw('gameplays.user_id',  //edited aft. your comment
                   DB::raw('users.name as user_name')))
          ->join('users', 'users.id', 'gameplays.user_id')
          ->groupBy('gameplays.user_id')
          ->orderBy('max_score', 'desc') //edited aft. comment
          ->limit(5); //limit to 5 players
```

Now get playerdata information and use `joinSub` to join the subquery (`$scores`):

```
$playerData = DB::table('playerdatas')
              ->joinSub($scores, 'max_scores', function($join){ //edited to max_scores
                   $join->on('max_scores.user_id', 'playerdatas.user_id');
              })
              ->orderBy('max_score', 'desc') //edited aft comment
              ->get();
```

---

The same in raw query would be:

```
select * from `playerdatas` 
inner join 
 (select MAX(score) as max_score, 
 gameplays.user_id from `gameplays` 
 inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `gameplays`.`user_id` 
 group by `gameplays`.`user_id` 
 order by `max_score` desc   
 limit 5) as `max_scores` on `max_scores`.`user_id` = `playerdatas`.`user_id` 
order by `max_score` desc
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, it didn't actually do what I wanted to do but that was close. I don't want to have sum of scores, just MAX score of every player and create ranking on that.

To make final query working I needed to set mysql strict_mode to false, due to sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your logic. But, I think the same query should work without turning changing full group by settings; you would just need to substitute `sum` with `max`..

Comment: Oh wait, my select is `users.id as user_id,` it should be `gamplays.user_id` and you dont need to alias it either, my mistake. If you changed that to `gamplays.user_id` you wouldnt need to change full group by settings.

Answer (score 1):

User Model

```
public function playerData(){
   return hasOne(App\PlayerData::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

GamePlay Model

```
public function game(){
   return belongsTo(App\Game::class, 'game_id', 'id');
}

public function user(){
   return belongsTo(App\User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Get all the gameplays for the game with given `game_id` and that satisfies the `created_at` condition(you mentioned in the post).

```
$gamePlays = GamePlay::with(['game', 'user.playerData'])
   ->where('game_id', $game_id)
   ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays($type))
   ->get();
```

Now we'll use methods available on collection. (`orderByDesc`, `groupBy`).

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#available-methods

Will contain all the user details required along with their top scores.

```
$users = collect([]);

foreach($gamePlays->groupBy('user_id') as $user_id => $gp_c){

    // $gp_c are the gameplays of that user from the above list that we obtained.

    // From those gameplays get the one with the highest score.

    $gp = $gp_c->sortByDesc('score')->first();
    
    // add the necessary details.
    $users.push([
         'id' => $user_id,
         'name' => $gp->user->name,
         'score' => $gp->score,
         'duration' => $gp->duration,
         'created_at' => $gp->created_at,
         'appearance' => $gp->user->playerData->appearance,
    ]);
}
```

Select the top 5(or less in case the number of users is < 5 ) users with highest score.

```
$top_users = $users->sortByDesc('score')->take( (sizeof($users) > 5) ? 5 : sizeof($users)));
```

Comment: Thanks for that answear, I think that might work well. I didn't go that way, because I think that would be less effecient than raw sql, but someday maybe I'll try that out and check how I'll work on real data

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, raw sql would be more efficient than this. But Eloquent ORM has its own beauty :) And even in the solution I just have one DB query, rest are all collection methods. Thanks :)