# Laravel Query with joins and subquery returns always same product

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying of get the product most selled of each community by the suppliers, However I'm getting always the product 1. My goal is only get one product "the most selled" according the community of the supplier.

This is my db schema:

[image]

And this is my current query using Laravel:

```
$products = Purchase::select([
    'purchases.supplier_id',
    'purchases.id as purchId',
    'suppliers.id as supliId',
    'suppliers.community_id',
    'purchase_details.product_id',
     'purchase_details.qty',
     'purchase_details.purchase_id',
  ])
  ->selectRaw('sum(purchase_details.qty) as sum')
  ->join('suppliers','purchases.supplier_id','suppliers.id')
  ->join('purchase_details','purchases.id','purchase_details.purchase_id')
  ->groupBy('suppliers.community_id')
  ->groupBy('purchase_details.product_id')
  ;
  

  $sql = $products->toSql();
  $result = \DB::table( \DB::raw("({$sql}) as sub") )
 ->mergeBindings($products->getQuery())
 ->groupBy('community_id')
 ->join('communities','sub.community_id','communities.id')
 ->leftJoin('products','sub.product_id','products.id')
 ->select('communities.name as communityName',
        'products.name as productName')

 ->selectRaw('max(sub.sum) as total_ventas')
 ->get();
return $result;
```

Output:

```
[
{
"communityName": "Chunchos",
"productName": "Product 1",
"total_ventas": "1.00"
},
{
"communityName": "Colpas",
"productName": "Product 1",
"total_ventas": "4.00"
},
{
"communityName": "Punas",
"productName": "Product 1",
"total_ventas": "8.00"
}
]
```

SQL Query output:

```
select `communities`.`name` as `communityName`,
    `products`.`name` as `productName`,
    max(sub.sum) as total_ventas 
    from (select `purchases`.`supplier_id`,
          `purchases`.`id` as `purchId`,
          `suppliers`.`id` as `supliId`,
          `suppliers`.`community_id`,
          `purchase_details`.`product_id`,
          `purchase_details`.`qty`,
          `purchase_details`.`purchase_id`,
          sum(purchase_details.qty) as sum from `purchases`
     inner join `suppliers` on `purchases`.`supplier_id` = `suppliers`.`id`
     inner join `purchase_details` 
  on `purchases`.`id` = `purchase_details`.`purchase_id`
  where `purchases`.`deleted_at` is null
  group by `suppliers`.`community_id`, `purchase_details`.`product_id`) as sub
  inner join `communities` on `sub`.`community_id` = `communities`.`id` 
  inner join `products` on `sub`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
  group by `community_id`
```

Why my joins are not working?

Comment: I would suggest getting the resulting SQL from the final query and adding it to the question, **after** properly indenting and formatting it.

Comment: Hi @miken32 I have updated my question, now I can't execute in phpmyadmin because of  this message `this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` could you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve incompatible with sql\_mode=only\_full\_group\_by in laravel eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776758/how-can-i-solve-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by-in-laravel-eloquen)

Comment: You can disable strict mode, or add all your grouping columns to your select. Looks like `community_id` on the outer query is causing the problem in this case.